Как сделать так, чтобы телеграм бот отвечал на видеосообщения(кружочки)?
Можно ли сделать по типу такого - @bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])?

Добро пожаловать на сайт, Tracelidi! Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой, как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Загрузка аудио сообщения, пример конвертации аудио в текст, исходный код конвертации

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video_note'])

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video_note'])
нашел ответ в комментарии, спасибо
